# What self-defense weapons are legal in England?

Tags: discussion

I still don't cotton why [What self-defense weapons are legal in England?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/142808/13759) was closed but not [What self defense items are allowed in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123452/13759).  I've tried to focus on one possibility here - when there's only one person attacking you and nobody's around.

Comment: As I indicated in a comment on one of your questions, each question is closed or re-opened on its own merits and sometimes questions stay open when the might need to be closed.

Comment: I agree with Willeke. In addition, I think the converse is true as well: because of the nature of the site's moderation process, sometimes questions are closed when they should have remained open.